# What's the probability that you find a working pen?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

You find a container of $27$ old pens in your
school supplies and continue to test them (without replacement), until you find
one that works. If each individual pen works $25$% of the time (regardless of the
other pens), what is the probability that you find one that works within the
first four tries?

My best guess was

$0.25 = \cfrac{1}{4}$ is the Probability of us having the 1st pen work ($0.25$ = probability of success)

$0.75 \cdot 0.25 = \cfrac{3}{16}$ is the probability of us having the 2nd pen work where $0.75$ is the probability of the 1st pen failing

$0.75 \cdot 0.75 \cdot 0.25 = \cfrac{9}{64}$ is the probability of us having the 3rd pen work where $0.75$ is the probability of the 1st and 2nd pen failing

$0.75 \cdot 0.75 \cdot 0.75 \cdot 0.25 = \cfrac{27}{256}$ is the probability of us having the 4th pen work $0.75$ is the probability of the 1st and 2nd and 3rd pen failing

So probability of us having a success within four tries $= \cfrac{1}{4} + \cfrac{3}{16} + \cfrac{9}{64} + \cfrac{27}{256} = \cfrac{175}{256}$

What I wanted to ask this website is if I had this right? I ask because the fact that they emphasize the fact that there's exactly 27 pens and that you test them without replacement makes me think that I'm missing a key step/have a logical flaw somewhere. Can someone tell me if I am a missing a step, because it feels like I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. The number $27$ is a bit of a red herring; it doesn't really matter how many there are (so long as there are at least four).

Another way to do it: suppose that all four pens fail. The chance of this is $$\left(\frac34\right)^4 = \frac{81}{256}.$$

Now, if that didn't happen, then at least one of them worked: $$1-\frac{81}{256}=\frac{175}{256}.$$

This agrees with your answer; the advantage is that it's a much simpler calculation, no matter how many pens you have to test (try both methods with all $27$ instead of $4$ pens...).

Comment: Ah I see, you just used the definition of the complement as your method correct?

Comment: @BillBillwater That's right.

Comment: Ok, thank you, this is much more easier then my method, I'll mark your answer as soon as I can as math stack exchange gives me a delay for some reason

Comment: @BillBillwater Glad to help!